# How to mock static methods using Moxie

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, moxiemocks

How can we mock static methods with Moxie framework (I should use only Moxie, because my organization allows only moxie in their environment.)

Suppose I have a class

```
public class Test{
  public int x;
  public int y;
  public static int add(){
    return x + y;
  }
}
```

I have to mock add class of Test using Moxie framework.

If I use like this

```
Test t = Moxie.mock(Test.class);
Moxie.stub(t).willReturn(20).when(t.add());
```

I get a warning saying that static method add should be accessed from type Test in a static way and also mocking does not happen when I run the test.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Your fields x and y should be static since your static function is accessing them. Also, you should call the function like this: Test.add().

Comment: Have you tried restructuring your code so it doesn't use static methods?

Comment: your add method doesn't need to be static here

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerMock along with moxie to mock static classes.

See http://moxiemocks.org/mvn/apidocs/index.html?moxie/MoxieRunner.html.

HTH,
Keshava.